# What is the philosophical doctrine that most closely corresponds to the listed positions?

Tags: ethics, terminology, meaning-of-life

I would like to ask for a possible classification of the following philosophical positions:

- Everything is a simple result of natural occurances and as such lacks
  any objective value. Even if a god existed and created us with a
  purpose in mind, that would still not give meaning to our lives. What
  gives meaning to the purpose for which our creator created us? (Think
  the Rick and Morty episode where Rick creates a small universe in
  order for the life forms in it to power his car).
- Humans are just very good biological learning machines. Our values
  and ethics are a result of natural selection and are passed into the
  next generation in part because of genes and in part because of
  parents driving and assisting their childrens' association process
  when young. Morals are relative and non-objective and just widely
  widespread.
- All human actions are driven by personal satisfaction (even
  "altruists", are altruists because in the end they gain more personal
  satisfaction by acting altruistically compared to the alternatives,
  mothers gain personal satisfaction by caring for their babies etc.)
- There is no inherit meaning in living but attempting to find and/or
  give meaning to our lives is a widespread cultural characteristic not
  necessarily inherit to us as a species. Therefore, a human can live
  happily by acknowledging that their lives has no meaning, that is, if
  they don't value life having an objective meaning.

Comment: This seems pretty "localized" :) --Is there any chance we could reframe this to ask what philosophy some *specific* idea might belong to?

Comment: I don't know who edited it to change "meaning" to "values"? The question made perfect sense in its original form and changing the word "meaning" to "values" changes its apparent intent. The OP should look into the edit, and maybe revert it.

Comment: I vote for reopen. The question asks for a philosophical classification which covers a series of philosophical views. The question does not ask whether the stated views are right or wrong. To me the question is neither opinion based nor pushing a personal view. In addition, the question seems very interesting because it possibly prompts different answers.

Comment: A broad term which covers your different views is **naturalist**. Naturalism is the view: "Everything can be explained by a natural mechanism, miracles do not happen." Of course a naturalist knows: At each point of time there are more questions than we can answer. Some questions have to be left open. Your naturalist position represents the following views concerning - religion: atheism - ethics: denial of objective ethical values, favoring a sociobiology approach - orientation: favouring explanations from science like the theory of evolution. - The poor layout is due to closing the question.

Comment: @JosephWeissman this is indeed localized but I don't see why it's against the rules. The OP definitely does not push a personal philosophy, just asks for a classification of his views. This can be objectively answered and as such the reason for closing seems a bit unreasonable.

Comment: My issues are mainly with the headline (which is not very specific or expressive) and the fact that even in the body I'm not really seeing any really specific *question* -- there's only one question-mark, and the question that's associated with appears rhetorical.

Comment: @veritas: that's just another way of doing the same.

Comment: Please consider asking whether some *specific idea* belongs to a particular philosophy. It will help if you can indicate what your research has uncovered so far.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. Asking for classification assistance =/= pushing opinions. The question is also obviously answerable and the reason for closing is that apparently it's not.

Comment: @Joseph Weissman I consider it a bit paternalistic to propose what the questioner shall ask - referring to your comment "Please consider ...". - I would prefer to see which answers will be given from the community to the question of the OP.

Comment: @JosephWeissman the question seems perfectly objective to me: the op lists a set of positions and then asks what school corresponds to them, the fact that they are personal views doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm actually fine with the immediate content but there are formal issues here that make it unfit for SE *as currently formulated*. The fuzziness of the headline is a big issue, which could be mitigated by narrowing the scope of the question to a particular issue. Keep in mind you can always ask more questions ("What is the philosophical basis for *specific idea*?")

Comment: @Joseph Weissman The question is characterized by the fact that it asks for a superordinate concept, which covers all(!) named positions, not just one specific position. - In plain words: You should not advice someone, who asks for the generic term for dogs and cats, to narrow down the scope of his question to dogs alone.

Comment: Again, this is mostly about fitness for SE. If I'm asking the question in your hypothetical, I would have a headline that asks: "What is the generic term for dogs and cats?" Which is perfectly fine, for something like ELL. This question headline is just asking us to play "name my philosophy" and should be much better-specified ("What is a philosophy that combines <specific idea> and <specific idea>?") --A multiplicity of components in a question is fine, but it should still be narrow (reasonably answerable in a few paragraphs, *able to be summarized as a specific question in the headline*.)

Comment: Let's bring this to meta for any further discussion.

Comment: @JosephWeissman Is the question a bit more appropriate for SE after the edit?

Answer (score 1):

The philosophical position closest to your world view is called [Existentialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism). From wikipedia:

> In the view of the existentialist, the individual's starting point is characterized by what has been called "the existential attitude", or a sense of disorientation and confusion in the face of an apparently meaningless or absurd world.

The idea of the world be absurd and meaningless was captured in their absurdist attitude:

> The notion of the Absurd contains the idea that there is no meaning in the world beyond what meaning we give it. This meaninglessness also encompasses the amorality or "unfairness" of the world. This contrasts with the notion that "bad things don't happen to good people"; to the world, metaphorically speaking, there is no such thing as a good person or a bad person; what happens happens, and it may just as well happen to a "good" person as to a "bad" person.

The key element for existentialists was [authenticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticity_(philosophy)): One should strive to be authentic and create their own meaning in life, as opposed to just following or copying others, or doing things for the sake of appearances. So objective meaning doesn't really matter (and shouldn't).

Most Existentialists were atheists (Sartre, Camus,...), but they could be christian as well, like Kierkegaard famously was.

Your world view is also similar in a way to Nietzsche's [Nihilism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism).